# Creating Storage Plugin throught through C# code in Apache Drill

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, apache-drill

I want to create Storage Plugin through C#(.NET) code, when Drill is install in some other system(not in local).?
   Is it Possible?? If yes then how.?

Comment: And what is the question? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first before asking non-questions.

Comment: Whether is it possible or not to create Storage Plugin through C#(.NET) code, when Drill is install in some other system(not in local).?  If yes then how..???

Answer (score 1):

I found out some solution for that:

```
           var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
           var postData = "name=" + name + "&config=" + config;
           var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           request.ContentLength = data.Length;
           using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
           {
               stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           }
           var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
           var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
           if (responseString != null)
           {
               var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
               return jsonObject.result == "success";
           }
```

Comment: @dev: Thanks dev.. it working..