# Enabling and Disabling Storage Plugin

Tags: apache-drill

```
 I am running Apache Drill in Window 8.1 OS, having latest version of Drill (1.7).
```

**I want to enable or disable storage plugin programatically (using C# code).**

Is there any way to do so.?

Answer (score 2):

You can update drill plugin via REST API.

I am taking MongoDB plugin as an example.

## Enable

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"mongoPlugin", "config":{"type":"mongo","enabled":true,"connection":"mongodb://localhost:27017/"}}' http://localhost:8047/storage/mongoPlugin.json
```

Change "enabled" to false to disable it.

## Disable

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"mongoPlugin", "config":{"type":"mongo","enabled":false,"connection":"mongodb://localhost:27017/"}}' http://localhost:8047/storage/mongoPlugin.json
```

Check drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/#post-/storage/%7Bname%7D.json) for more details.

You already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36008500/3929393) about creating plugins using C#. Just change payload as mentioned above.

Comment: :- In previous version of drill (i.e:- 1.6), Enabling & Disabling working fine through code. but in latest version (i.e:- 1.7) , Its not working properly, Even though its not giving any error.

Comment: :- Can you please tell me curl command for creating storage plugin for MYSQL.

Comment: @Sanjiv command is common for create/update. Use same above mentioned command

Comment: :- While creating plugin for MySQL database using same command , its showing error:- curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jdbc,could not resolve host: driver, could not resolve host: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,url.....etc

Comment: :- This is my code:-  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"myplug","type": "jdbc",  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","username": "root","password": "*****","enabled": true}}' http://localhost:8047/storage/myplug.json

Comment: You forgot config. Use- `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"myplug", "config":{"type": "jdbc", "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","username": "root","password": "*****","enabled": true}}' localhost:8047/storage/myplug.json
`

Comment: but other command are working fine. I fire command for enabling and disabling storage plugin its working fine. here command for enabling storage plugin:- curl http://localhost:8047/storage/DemoMySQl/enable/true (Enabling)

Comment: @Sanjiv check my last comment

Comment: its response can be 
`{"result" : "success"}` or `{"result" : "error (unable to create/ update storage)"}`

Comment: :- Then What this error means: curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 8
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jdbc,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: driver
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,url
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jdbc:mysql
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 5
Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@478ce1c2; line: 1, column: 2

Comment: :- Select Query is also not working through curl :--- Query:-   curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "select * from cp.`employee.json` limit 10"}' http://localhost:8047/query.json

Comment: @Sanjiv If given solution is not working no need to accept/upvote the answer. I am not here for reputations.

Comment: :- See Dev your command for enabling or disabling plugins are working file. But check my question.. I am asking different curl command question(i.e:- for select query ). I am not giving you any points or reputation. I am accepting your answer beacuse if other user facing this problem, they can refer your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118540/discussion-between-sanjiv-and-dev-).

Answer (score 1):

For Enabling or Disabling Storage Plugin in Window Environment. First we have to download curl.exe file from [Download Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=tar.bz2) 
. Set the path of curl.exe file in Environment Variable:-

**Follow these steps:-**
Download curl zip
Extract the contents (if you have downloaded the correct version you should find curl.exe)
Place curl.exe in a folder where you keep your software (e.g. D:\software\curl\curl.exe)
To run curl from the command line

a) Right-hand-click on "My Computer" icon

b) Select Properties

c) Click 'Advanced system settings' link

d) Go to tab [Advanced] - 'Environment Variables' button

e) Under System variable select 'Path' and Edit button

f) Add a semicolon followed by the path to where you placed your curl.exe (e.g. ;D:\software\curl).

Now Open Command Prompt and run following command:-

**For Disabling Storage Plugin:-**

```
curl http://localhost:8047/storage/DemoMySQl/enable/false
```

**For Enabling:-**

```
curl http://localhost:8047/storage/DemoMySQl/enable/true
```

> Note:- DemoMySQl is storage plugin name.